# Google Drive API - Get folders list

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I have some folders in Google Drive (lets assume, that I have them in the Root folder).

How can I parse them from Drive as `folderName` and `driveId`?

I'd like to do it with Google Drive API Google Drive API, not with REST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup Google Drive API for Android in your project. Everything is in guides/documentation on Google Drive API site. Here is link to [get started](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started)

Then you will do like this:

1. Get root folder by calling  `DriveApi.getRootFolder`
2. Get children of the root folder by calling method `listChildren` [(Link to documentation)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveFolder#listChildren(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) on folder returned in step 1
3. Process result by getting [Metadata](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/Metadata) from buffer
4. Get file by calling DriveID object method `asDriveFile()` [(Link to documentation)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveId#asDriveFile())

Comment: I can get results from `listChildren` like this `result.getMetadataBuffer()`?

Comment: I'm constantly getting error "incompatible type - this is a DriveFile, use `asDriveFile` instead", the same goes for `asDriveFolder`. Any way to check if `DriveId` file or folder?

Comment: You can use  `getResourceType()` and compare to  static field https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveId.html#getResourceType()

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bit of experience with rxjava I would suggest you to take a look at this library: https://github.com/francescocervone/RxDrive
Otherwise you could do the same things without rxjava, official documentation has some examples for basic operations, also [this quickstart](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart) might help